# await only valid with async function urban dictionary api discord js

Tags: javascript, api, asynchronous, discord

Any idea how i can fix this problem? I tried putting an async function in and I couldn't get it to work. I'm not quite sure on how or where to add the async function, and how to get the two to work together. Any help is much appreciated, and this is for a discord javascript bot.

```
client.on('message', message => {
if (message.content.startsWith(`${PREFIX}urban`)) {
  if (!args.length) {
    return message.channel.send('You need to supply a search term!');
  }

    const query = querystring.stringify({ term: args.join(' ') });
  const { list } = await fetch(`https://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?${query}`).then(response => response.json());
  
  if (!list.length) {
    return message.channel.send(`No results found for **${args.join(' ')}**.`);
  }

  const [answer] = list;

  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#EFFF00')
    .setTitle(answer.word)
    .setURL(answer.permalink)
    .addFields(
      { name: 'Definition', value: trim(answer.definition, 1024) },
      { name: 'Example', value: trim(answer.example, 1024) },
      { name: 'Rating', value: `${answer.thumbs_up} thumbs up. ${answer.thumbs_down} thumbs down.` },
    );
  message.channel.send(embed);
}
});
```

Comment: added an answer, let me know if it works or not

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=await+is+only+valid+in+async+function+is%3aq

Answer (score 0):

In order to run your `await` command, you have to put `async` at the top of your code. For more info about how `await` and `async` work, look at the [link provided by VLAZ](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=await+is+only+valid+in+async+function+is%3aq).

```
//put the async right before the second message, that's it
client.on('message', async message => {
if (message.content.startsWith(`${PREFIX}urban`)) {
  if (!args.length) {
    return message.channel.send('You need to supply a search term!');
  }

    const query = querystring.stringify({ term: args.join(' ') });
  const { list } = await fetch(`https://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?${query}`).then(response => response.json());
  
  if (!list.length) {
    return message.channel.send(`No results found for **${args.join(' ')}**.`);
  }

  const [answer] = list;

  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#EFFF00')
    .setTitle(answer.word)
    .setURL(answer.permalink)
    .addFields(
      { name: 'Definition', value: trim(answer.definition, 1024) },
      { name: 'Example', value: trim(answer.example, 1024) },
      { name: 'Rating', value: `${answer.thumbs_up} thumbs up. ${answer.thumbs_down} thumbs down.` },
    );
  message.channel.send(embed);
}
});
```